# A method to remove duplicates from a multi dimensional array by comparing specific values

Tags: python

I am writing a python script for data preprocessing. The data in question is read and stored within the script as a multi dimensional array consisting of data points similar to the ones below.

```
[['United', '-27.654379', '152.917741', 'e10', '1459', '2019-03-18'],
['United', '-27.654379', '152.917741', 'e10', '1449', '2019-03-19']]
```

Currently i need too remove values within the array that have identical dates so that

```
[['Costco', '-27.213607', '152.996416', 'e10', '1237', '2019-03-16'],
['United', '-25.607894', '150.367213', 'e10', '1297', '2019-03-16']]
```

Would become

```
[['Costco', '-27.213607', '152.996416', 'e10', '1237', '2019-03-16']]
```

My current method of doing so (shown below) appears to identify and remove entries with duplicate dates, but some can still be found within the output.

```py
    for line in Data_text:
        for row in Data_text:
            if line[5] == row[5]:
                Data_text.remove(row)
```

Any insight into the faults in my algorithm and/or a better way of doing it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure Python, you can leverage the power of `set` to work in this case:

```
lst = [['Costco', '-27.213607', '152.996416', 'e10', '1237', '2019-03-16'],
       ['Costco', '-27.213607', '152.996416', 'e10', '1297', '2019-03-16']]

seen = set()
print([x for x in lst if not (x[5] in seen or seen.add(x[5]))])

# [['Costco', '-27.213607', '152.996416', 'e10', '1237', '2019-03-16']]
```

Answer (score 0):

With python3.7, the code below just works. However, it reserves the last one.

```
data = [['Costco', '-27.213607', '152.996416', 'e10', '1237', '2019-03-16'],
        ['United', '-25.607894', '150.367213', 'e10', '1297', '2019-03-16']]

data = list({item[5]: item for item in data}.values())
# [['United', '-25.607894', '150.367213', 'e10', '1297', '2019-03-16']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider pandas for this type of data and operations:

```
a = [['Costco', '-27.213607', '152.996416', 'e10', '1237', '2019-03-16'],
     ['United', '-25.607894', '150.367213', 'e10', '1297', '2019-03-16']]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a).drop_duplicates(5, keep='first')
```

Result:

```
df

        0           1           2    3     4           5
0  Costco  -27.213607  152.996416  e10  1237  2019-03-16
```

This is especially useful if the dates have different formats:

```
a2 = [['Costco', '-27.213607', '152.996416', 'e10', '1237', 'March 16, 2019'],
    ['United', '-25.607894', '150.367213', 'e10', '1297', '2019-03-16']]

df = pd.DataFrame(a2)
df[5] = pd.to_datetime(df[5])
df.drop_duplicates(5, keep='first')
```

Still gives correct result:

```
        0           1           2    3     4          5
0  Costco  -27.213607  152.996416  e10  1237 2019-03-16
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some problem about this line :  Data_text.remove(row)  the Data_text length will decrease 1

Please try this , new a result_list = [],  put the no duplicate record into result_list

```
result_list = []
length = len(Data_text);
for i in range(0, length):
    line = Data_text[i]
    is_exsit = False
    for row in result_list:
        if line[5] == row[5]:
            is_exsit = True
            break

    if is_exsit == False:
        result_list.append(line)


print(result_list)
```